# React- selecting radio button for one question changes all other questions' choices

Tags: html, reactjs

I am working on a questionnaire and got 50 questions in React.
When I select one option for single question it effects all other questions and selects the same option for them.
Sandbox link is in the end if you wanna play with code.

Here is my Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default function Header({ questions }) {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState(questions);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    selectedOption: ""
  });

  const submitHandler = () => {
    console.log("asdasd");
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setState({ ...state, selectedOption: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1 className="title">
          Personality Identification using Machine Learning
        </h1>
        <h2 className="description">
          Please Answer following 50 Questions to Detect your personality type
        </h2>
      </header>

      <ol className="questions">
        {question.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <li
                key={uuidv4()}
                className="question"
                name={`question_${question.indexOf(item)}`}
              >
                <h3>{item.question}</h3>
                <form className="choices">
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[0]}
                        checked={state.selectedOption === "1"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                      <span>Agree</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[1]}
                        checked={state.selectedOption === "2"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                      <span>Strongly agree</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[2]}
                        checked={state.selectedOption === "3"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                      <span>Neutral</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[3]}
                        checked={state.selectedOption === "4"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                      <span>Disagree</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[4]}
                        checked={state.selectedOption === "5"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      />
                      <span>Strongly Disagree</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </li>
              <hr />
            </>
          );
        })}
      </ol>
      <div className="button_container">
        <button className="btn" onClick={submitHandler}>
          <span>Submit</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my questions Data

```
export default [
  {
    question: "I am the life of the party.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
  {
    question: "I feel little concern for others.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
  {
    question: "I am always prepared.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
  {
    question: "I get stressed out easily.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
  {
    question: "I have a rich vocabulary.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
  {
    question: "I don't talk a lot.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
 
  {
    question: "I have difficulty understanding abstract ideas.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
  {
    question: "I feel comfortable around people.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
  {
    question: "I insult people.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
  {
    question: "I pay attention to details.",
    choices: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  },
 
  
];
```

> Here is the sandbox link: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-paper-9j26u)

Comment: That's because you are setting selectedOption as a string in the state. So all of the questions consider that as the answer. Give each question an ID and change selectedOption to an object such that it contains {id: val}. That way, in the checked attribute, you can check selectedOption[id] instead of just selectedOption

Comment: yup that's what i was looking for <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we console log your `state` after selecting any of the 'Agree' options, your `state` looks like this...

```
{selectedOption: "1"}
```

...all of your components that you are mapping are rendering the checked box as 'checked', on the condition that...

```
state.selectedOption == 1
```

...so it would be expected that all boxes in your form would check. The solution to this is to make the condition unique to each checkbox...

1. I renamed `state` to `selections`, as naming it state is confusing, as you have multiple states.
2. Secondly, on initialisation of `selections`, it is set to an array equaling the number of questions you have.
3. I added `index` as an argument to your map
4. Your handleChange function now takes two arguments...

   1. `index` -> the index of the form from the map
   2. `selection` -> the choice from the form

...copies the original `selections` array, and changes the index of the `selections` array to the `selection` argument we passed. eg. agree on the first form iteration if we passed two questions, it would change the 'selections' state from `[], []` to `[1], []`

5. The checked condition now looks to see if the `selections` array matches the number assigned to each selection.
6. Finally we pass the selection number and the index to handleChange.

The selections now all work independently and logging the `selected` state on submit gives us something like this...

{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1}
0: 1
1: 2
2: 1

..where the first three questions have been selected Agree, Strongly Agree and Agree (I'd also put strongly agree above agree).

Here is the working code in a sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-bassi-g8bby?file=/src/Header.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default function Header({ questions }) {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState(questions);
  const [selections, setSelections] = useState([Object.keys(questions).map(x => [])]);

  const submitHandler = () => {
    console.log(selections);
  };
  const handleChange = (selection, index) => {
    let tempState = {...selections}
    tempState[index] = selection
    setSelections(tempState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1 className="title">
          Personality Identification using Machine Learning
        </h1>
        <h2 className="description">
          Please Answer following 50 Questions to Detect your personality type
        </h2>
      </header>

      <ol className="questions">
        {question.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <li
                key={uuidv4()}
                className="question"
                name={`question_${question.indexOf(item)}`}
              >
                <h3>{item.question}</h3>
                <form className="choices">
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[0]}
                        checked={selections[index] === 1}
                        onChange={() => handleChange(1, index)}
                      />
                      <span>Agree</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[1]}
                        checked={selections[index] === 2}
                        onChange={() => handleChange(2, index)}
                      />
                      <span>Strongly agree</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[2]}
                        checked={selections[index] === 3}
                        onChange={() => handleChange(3, index)}
                      />
                      <span>Neutral</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[3]}
                        checked={selections[index] === 4}
                        onChange={() => handleChange(4, index)}
                      />
                      <span>Disagree</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        name="choice"
                        value={item.choices[4]}
                        checked={selections[index] === 5}
                        onChange={() => handleChange(5, index)}
                      />
                      <span>Strongly Disagree</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </li>
              <hr />
            </>
          );
        })}
      </ol>
      <div className="button_container">
        <button className="btn" onClick={submitHandler}>
          <span>Submit</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```